# How to setup DocuSign Notification Reminders using C# SDK

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to setup Reminder Delay and Reminder Frequency using DocuSign C# SDK.

Here is my code:

```
var envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition {Status = Enums.DocumentStatus.Sent.ToString()};

envelope.Notification = new Notification();
envelope.Notification.Reminders = new Reminders();

envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderEnabled = "true";
envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderFrequency = "10";
envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderDelay = "5";
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried to send document from the DocuSign site using same values for Reminders and after that read Notification info using API:

```
var api = new EnvelopesApi();
var envelope = api.GetEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId);
var isEnabled = envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderEnabled;
```

But in this case all values are null.

What is the correct workflow to setup Reminders using DocuSign C# SDK?

Comment: Notification settings can be obtained from `EnvelopesApi` using `GetNotificationSettings` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the UseAccountDefaults property of the Notification object to false:

```
envelope.Notification.UseAccountDefaults = false.ToString();
```

For SOAP API:

```
envelope.Notification.UseAccountDefaults = false;
envelope.Notification.UseAccountDefaultsSpecified = true;
```

Comment: `envelope.Notification.UseAccountDefaults = false.ToString();` worked for me. But I did not find definition for `UseAccountDefaultsSpecified`.